# How to access values from Static Char in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I Declare values as a static set of Char,

```
   static char month[][15]={"January","February","March","April","May","June", "July","August","September","October","November","December"};
```

Now, I want to access value from index 5 in defined char month[15];

How it is possible in objective-c? help me.

Comment: Objective-C is a strict superset of "C" so you access it exactly the same was as in "C". Objective-C is "C".

Comment: you can create Enum for that....

Comment: For quick testing there is an OSX app: "CodeRunner", well worth the price.

Comment: @Spynet Not so much, an enum does not provide it's members as strings. Try it.

Comment: Why are you coding Objective-C without knowing the basics of C???

Comment: @HotLicks, actually we should define Static Array of elements, but i defined here Static char set array elements, i need particular index element as a string, can you tell me, how to define in NSString

Answer (score 2):

You can access it Using , **month[index]**

```
NSLog(@"%s",month[5]);
```

It same as You are working with char array in **C**..